# Salvar projeto do IntelliJ como .java

Tags: java, intellij

comecei tem uma semana um curso de programação, porém não sou da área de TI e afins o que está me dificultando muito o aprendizado. Gostaria de saber se tem como vocês me ajudarem neste meu primeiro empecilho.

O professor pediu para criar um projeto que nos permitisse escrever "Hello World", isso eu consegui fazer. Porém, pediu para salvar como .java e fazer o upload no mystat (programa do curso para carregar os deveres de casa), aí isso eu não to sabendo como fazer. Alguém pode me dar uma luz, por favor?

Comment: A resposta do @Igor explica bem, mas tenha em mente que o arquivo ".java" terá o mesmo nome da sua Classe, portanto, você pode pesquisar no seu computador por esse nome caso esteja com dificuldade de encontrar o arquivo da classe .java

Answer (score -1):

### Contextualização

Java é uma linguagem *orientada a objetos*.

Uma linguagem orientada a objetos é composta por *classes* e *interfaces* basicamente.

Toda classe (e interface) em Java é um arquivo texto com a extensão `.java`.

O arquivo que você implementou (escreveu) a lógica solicitada no exercício é uma **classe** Java que deve ter a extensão `.java`.

---

### Salvar como `.java`

Se você escreveu seu código e ele funcionou com certeza você já o salvou como `.java`.

O que você precisa fazer chegar até a pasta do seu projeto pelo Windows Explorer  e encontrar a classe que você criou e escreveu seu código. Esse arquivo pode ter qualquer nome mas **deve** ter a extensão `.java`.

É essa classe que seu professor quer que você faça o upload.